# Disable SSMS Connect to server button

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

how do i disable the connect button of the SSMS?
i need to prevent user to creating extra unauthorized connection.

http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6959/25398783.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

You need to rethink your security policy. Don't give unauthorized users the password. Restrict actions that can be performed on the database using permissions, stored procedures, etc.